# Swift operators for protocols

Tags: swift

Say I have two structs that conform to a protocol,

```
protocol NumberType {
    var doubleValue: Double { get }
}

struct Rational: NumberType {
    let numerator: Int
    let denominator: Int
    var doubleValue: Double { get { return Double(numerator) / Double(denominator) } }
}

struct FixedPoint: NumberType {
    let value: Double
    var doubleValue: Double { get { return value } }
}
```

And I want to define arithmetic operators for `NumberType` that will in turn return `NumberType`s.

```
func *(lhs: NumberType, rhs: NumberType) -> NumberType { return FixedPoint(lhs.doubleValue * rhs.doubleValue) }
```

But I also want to add more specific operators so when both are `Rational`s, I return a `Rational`.

```
func *(lhs: Rational, rhs: Rational) -> NumberType { return Rational(...) }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this than to have one super-function per operator that does all type checking?

## Edits

You should be able to multiply FixedPoint by Rational, since they both conform to NumberType.

The overloading strategy won't work, because if I do `a * b * c` where all values are `Rational`, the result of `a * b` is `NumberType`, and so `(a * b) * c` will fall back to using the generic `NumberType` multiplication operator. I'll lose my precision here.

I'm not bothered about being able to multiply by `Doubles`, `Ints` etc.

## Further Edits

It's not correct to assume that the most generic case always returns a `FixedPoint`. I'm showing basic usage here, but if you have a `FixedPoint` equal to `0`, and another `Rational`, and you wanted to add them, it's feasible that you could get a `Rational` in your most generic case.

Comment: Fixed point should be able to be multiplied by a rational using the most generic form, NumberType * NumberType.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the example. The most generic version returns a FixedPoint.

Comment: I hope you realise that your `FixedPoint` implementation uses a floating-point type to store the value ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use generics here...

If you define the protocol like...

```
protocol NumberType {    
    var doubleValue: Double { get }

    init(doubleValue double: Double)
}
```

Then you could define a function like...

```
func *<T: NumberType>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T {
    return T(doubleValue: lhs.doubleValue * rhs.doubleValue)
}
```

This will allow you to use this function with any type of object as long as it conforms to `NumberType`. The only caveat is that both `lhs` and `rhs` must be the same type.

Then in the implementation of each NumberType you can define how the init works...

```
struct FixedPoint: NumberType {
    let value: Double
    var doubleValue: Double { get { return value } }

    init(doubleValue double: Double) {
        // this implementation may not be practical for things like Rationals etc...
        self.value = double
    }
}
```

Without having some common way of creating `NumberTypes` then you'd have to have multiple implementations of how the function works and therefore have your method of creating multiple instance depending on what the inputs are.

Comment: I've clarified the wording in the post. I want a NumberType returned.

Comment: @JacobParker edited slightly to show how you could implement it but it may not be practical.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the protocol declare a function that does what you want.

```
protocol NumberType {
    var doubleValue: Double { get }
    func multipliedBy(other: NumberType) -> NumberType
}
```

And then define the operator

```
func *(l: NumberType, r: NumberType) -> NumberType
{
    return l.multipliedBy(other: r)
}
```

Each type that implements the protocol, implements `multipliedBy(other:)` in a way that is suitable for its type.

Comment: The problem with this (and why you would use generics) is that you could use a Rational and a FixedPoint as inputs... and what would you want as an output?

Comment: @Frogmeister You would want a `NumberType` as the output. You'd let `Rational` decide what to do if it is being multiplied by a type that is not a `Rational`

Comment: Yes, but `NumberType` isn't a type. If you wanted to be able to accept two separate number types then I'd still create the signature like... `func *<T: NumberType, U: NumberType>(lhs: T, rhs: U) -> T` for instance. i.e. always return an object of the type of `lhs`. Or remove `U` entirely and only allow homogeneous use of the operator (which is the Swift standard for operators) and have the user (dev) convert to homogeneous types before using it.

Comment: @Fogmeister `NumberType` is perfectly fine used as a type. It means "any type that conforms to this protocol".

Comment: @Fogmeister And there is nothing in Swift that says operators have to have homogenous types.

Comment: No, but try adding a Double and an Float. It's a commonly used standard across the whole of Swift. :)

Comment: @Fogmeister So you can't add Doubles and Ints. Who cares? There seems to be a lot of ideological bullshit in the Swift community that is sometimes detrimental to the language. For example the shift operators would certainly benefit from breaking your alleged rule.

Comment: I never said it was a rule. I just find your definition of the function very ambiguous. I could put in a Rational and a FixedPoint and get out ANY of the however many other types that conform to `NumberType`.

Comment: @Fogmeister But why would you care? As long as it is a NumberType, the implementation is unimportant.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Also, lets keep bad language out of StackOverflow... it doesn't reflect well on the community.